# Evaluate the integral using Euler integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{7+x^7} \ dx$$
I want to evaluate this using the Euler integral. What I have tried:

I tried to make a substitution, because I want to evaluate it via gamma integrals. But I can not find the substitution. Can somebody help me with the substitution?

My attempt:

I made the substitution $$t = \frac{1}{7}x^7, \ \ \ x = (7x)^{1/7}, \ \ \ dx = (7t)^{-6/7} dt, \ \ \ \Rightarrow x^{1/2} = (7t)^{1/14}$$ I fill in and receive:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{7+x^7} \ dx = \frac{1}{7} \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+\frac{1}{7}x^7} \ dx = \frac{7^{(-11/14)}}{7}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{t^{(1/14) - (6/7)}}{1+t} \ dt$$
After that, I continued: $$\frac{7^{(-11/14)}}{7}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{t^{(-11/14)}}{1+t} \ dt = \frac{7^{(-11/14)}}{7} B(\frac{3}{14}, 1-\frac{3}{14}) = \frac{7^{(-11/14)}}{7} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{3}{14})\cdot \Gamma(1-\frac{3}{14})}{\Gamma(1)} = \frac{7^{(-11/14)}}{7}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{14})}$$

But the answer has to be $\frac{1}{7^{25/14}}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{14})}$ Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Try $t = \frac{1}{7}x^7  \Leftrightarrow x = (7t)^{1/7}$.

Comment: I am going to try it, thanks

Comment: After making that substitution, the formula http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E3 should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the change of variable
$$
t=\frac{x^7}7,\quad x=(7t)^{1/7},\quad dx=(7t)^{-6/7}dt,
$$ one is led to the [Euler beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties)
$$
B(x,y) = \int_0^\infty\frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}\,dt=\frac{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}, \quad \operatorname{Re}(x)>0,\ \operatorname{Re}(y)>0. 
$$Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Can you please check my updated question? Can you tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: When you wrote $t = \frac 1 7 x^7$ you went on to make a mess -- it should be $x = (7t)^{1/7}$ and so $\frac {dx} {dt} = t^{-6/7}$.

Comment: The derivative of $(7t)^{1/7} = (7t)^{-6/7}$, right?

Comment: @Paul D'oh! Just noticed the $7$ is inside the bracket! Sorry.

Comment: I found the mistake, I changed it. Thanks for your help